# Python - how to create changeable return variable?

Tags: python

I want to predefine the return value of a function and change it's elements during my function.
So, i.e. let us define

```
def myFunc()
    properties = ["value","num", "comment"]
    elements = []
    parts = {"properties":properties, "elements":elements}    
    error = 0
    errorMsg = ""
    result = [parts, error, errorMsg]
    
    .... # do all the stuff

    return result
```

In case something goes wrong, I would like to change error to an error code and add an error message. If everything went well, `elements` will contain some elements.

I understand, why this will always return `error=0`. It is because in `result` there is not stored a reference to error, there is stored the same reference, that `error` has had in the moment when `result` was created.

So how can I achieve, that the return value will also be changed, when chaning it's elements?
I know, that

```
error = [0]
errorMsg = [""]
```

together with

```
error[0]=1
errorMsg[0]="error"
```

works, but in this case, the return value `res[1]` is a list and not the value itself.

Comment: Why not just `result[1] = 1`? Lists in Python are not immutable; they can be changed after creating them.

Comment: because, when I later will change `result` to `result=[parts, NEW_ITEM, error, errorMsg]` then `result[1]=1` will change the wrong element.
In C I would define `result` as a struct and access it's elements by name. So changing the struct does not imply further investigantions on my function

Comment: Then you should use a dictionary or a namedtuple here, instead of a list. (Aside: the Pythonic way to report errors is to raise an exception, not to return an error code. If you do that, you could just return the actual result and don't need to wrap it at all.)

Comment: but I think, tuples are immutable!?

Comment: Sorry, I thought [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) fields could be assigned to, but I was wrong. Then either use a dict, create your own class, or take my advice about Pythonic error reporting :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try a try except statement, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but it may work:

```
try:
    return result
except Exception as e:
    errorMsg = e + " has gone wrong!"
    return errorMsg
```

This uses errorMsg as a string and not a list like you had it, but I believe this should work